# Why does one extension mutate but the other doesn't

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm playing around with C# extensions and am confused about mutate methods.

Below are two code samples that are supposed to change the calling List.  The first (shuffle) works but the second (CustomExtension) leaves the List unchanged.

At the end of the CustomExtension call the list parameter looks to be changed, but on returning from the method the List looks untouched.

Why does one work and the other doesn't?  What's going on?

**This works.**

```
readonly private static Random rng = new Random();
public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
{

    int n = list.Count;
    while (n < 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = rng.Next(n + 1);
        T value = list[k];
        list[k] = list[n];
        list[n] = value;
    }
}
myList.Shuffle();
```

(The above was ripped from [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt))

**This Doesn't**

```
static void CustomExtension(this IList<int> list)
{
    list = new List<int>() { 9, 10, 11 };
}
foo.CustomExtension();
```

Comment: Just so happens Microsoft has preempted this sort of question and documented it thoroughly (since the beginning of C# time) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters

Comment: @TheGeneral That article doesn't mention extension-methods or the fact you can't have a `ref this` parameter though.

Comment: @Dai, yeah you are correct, on a side note, didn't they allow the first parameter of extension methods to use ref since C# 7.2 ?

Comment: For future weary traveller, here is the documentation for extension methods. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods#common-usage-patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you're overwriting elements inside the `List<T>`. This mutates the list in-place.

In the second example you're creating a new list and replacing the **local reference** `list` which is a parameter which is **not** being passed using `ref`, so it has no effect outside of the scope of the method. Your `foo` instance is not being mutated in `CustomExtension`.

Extension methods in C# cannot pass the `this` parameter using `ref` so you cannot overwrite the caller's instance reference.

If you change the method and call-site to a normal method with a `ref` parameter, then it works as expected (but it still isn't mutating `foo`, it's replacing it):

```
static void CustomExtension(ref IList<int> list)
{
    list = new List<int>() { 9, 10, 11 };
}

CustomExtension( ref foo );
```